# android studio - how to stop runnable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

please teach me how to stop my runnable.
"handler.removeCallback(sS)" does not work.
Or is my program wrong?

```
int life = 100, damage = 5;
public void gameOver()
{
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
final Runnable sS = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            life = life - damage;
            String lifeHP = String.valueOf(life);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(lifeHP);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
            if (life < 0 )
            {
                gameOver();
                //handler.removeCallback(ss)--does not work.
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(sS);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Runnable on button click in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188398/how-to-stop-runnable-on-button-click-in-android)

Comment: hmm...looks when only callback is removed...there is a message in the queue...which when executes assigns the runnable back to handler...I think you need to use removeCallbacksAndMessages here.